# py2neo: index.get_or_create() or graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node()

Tags: py2neo

When you add an indexed node in py2neo 1.6.0, you have two options:

```
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
```

Option 1:

```
index = graph_db.get_or_create_index('Myindex')
indexed_node = index.get_or_create('key', 'value', {node props})
```

Option 2:

```
index = graph_db.get_or_create_index('Myindex')
indexed_node = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node('Myindex', 'key', 'value', {node props})
```

I.e. you can add the node via the Index or via the GraphDatabaseService.

Does it make a difference which one I use? Or are these just wrappers for the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the options you show will achieve the same result and are almost idenitical. In Option 2, however, your first line is redundant. The `graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node` method is a shortcut that creates both the index (if it does not already exist) and the node in a single call.

Comment: Good to know! I'll stick to Option 1, helps me to understand my code in 3 months ;)